# eslint error Unsafe member access ['content-type'] on an any value

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

The following eslint errors are generated by the code below :

> @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access: Unsafe member access ['content-type'] on an any value.

```js
export const getGraphPhoto = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await getGraphDetails(
      config.resources.msGraphPhoto.uri,
      config.resources.msGraphPhoto.scopes,
      { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }
    )
    if (!(response && response.data)) {
      return ''
    }
    const imageBase64 = new Buffer(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64')
    return `data:${response.headers['content-type']};base64, ${imageBase64}`
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Failed retrieving the graph photo: ${error as string}`)
  }
}
```

The promise `getGraphDetails` returns `Promise<AxiosResponse<any>>`

The issue is clearly that the property `response.headers['content-type']` might not be present on the `response` object. To fix this I tried checking for it first but that doesn't get rid of the warning:

```js
    if (
      !(response && response.data && response.headers && response.headers['content-type'])
    ) { return '' }
```

Thank you for any guidance you can give me to better understand and solve this issue.

[image]

Comment: These errors are simply being logged, aren't they? I mean, they're not blocking errors that prevent your application from running

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used TypeScript in a while so I hope I don't make any mistakes... I think that the intention of the rule is not to prevent access to a property that does not exist but to warn of the access to a property of any object typified as `any` (explicitly or implicitly). The rule doesn't take into account if there is code checking that this property exists but simply the type of the object. If it is not warning about accessing to `response.data` or `response.headers` but only to `response. headers['content-type']`, I guess that `getGraphDetails` response is typed but `headers` property is typed as `any`. I think you have three options:

- Set the type to the response headers. I'm not sure if you could find one in an existing project but, if not, you could declare an Interface as explicit as you want to fit your needs and use it like this:

```js
interface ResponseHeaders {
  'content-type': string,
  [key: string]: string, // you could set more explicit headers names or even remove the above and set just this line
}
const headers : ResponseHeaders = response.headers;
```

- Disable the rule for this line or the entire file.
- Ignore the warning.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you. One thing I wonder is why TypeScript itself is not tripping over this and only the linter complains?